# Exporting Outlook Email to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, export

Good Day! I am new to VBA. I am trying to export e-mails from Outlook to Excel automatically with the help of some VBA scripts which are available online. I am ended up with 80% result. Please look at the code that I have used. In that, I need to add some codes to export **mail body** also. Someone please guide me.

```
Public WithEvents objMails As Outlook.Items


Private Sub Application_Startup()

    Set objMails = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items

End Sub



Private Sub objMails_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem

    Dim strExcelFile As String

    Dim objExcelApp As Excel.Application

    Dim objExcelWorkBook As Excel.Workbook

    Dim objExcelWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    Dim nNextEmptyRow As Integer

    Dim strColumnB As String

    Dim strColumnC As String

    Dim strColumnD As String

    Dim strColumnE As String

    If Item.Class = olMail Then
       Set objMail = Item
    End If


    strExcelFile = "d:\LocalData\Z018439\Desktop\MY\NX-AMO\Mail Export\export.xlsx"


    On Error Resume Next
    Set objExcelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Error <> 0 Then
       Set objExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    Set objExcelWorkBook = objExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(strExcelFile)
    Set objExcelWorkSheet = objExcelWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")


    nNextEmptyRow = objExcelWorkSheet.Range("B" & objExcelWorkSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    strColumnB = objMail.SenderName
    strColumnC = objMail.SenderEmailAddress
    strColumnD = objMail.Subject
    strColumnE = objMail.ReceivedTime


    If StrComp(strColumnB, "service_manager7@mail.nissan.co.jp", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then

    objExcelWorkSheet.Range("A" & nNextEmptyRow) = nNextEmptyRow - 1
    objExcelWorkSheet.Range("B" & nNextEmptyRow) = strColumnB
    objExcelWorkSheet.Range("C" & nNextEmptyRow) = strColumnC
    objExcelWorkSheet.Range("D" & nNextEmptyRow) = strColumnD
    objExcelWorkSheet.Range("E" & nNextEmptyRow) = strColumnE


    objExcelWorkSheet.Columns("A:E").AutoFit


    objExcelWorkBook.Close SaveChanges:=True


    End If

    objExcelApp.Quit


    Set objExcelApp = Nothing


Set objExcelWorkBook = Nothing



  Set objExcelWorkSheet = Nothing



   Set objMail = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Does VB.Net use `Set` statements??  I thought that was only required in VBA.

Comment: @YowE3K : Nope. `Set` doesn't even exist in VB.NET (or at least not in that context). This should be tagged with VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Body is just as you'd think.

```
strColumnF = objMail.Body
```

You also have `objMail.HTMLBody` (which will show the body with html tags), `CreationTime`, `FlagStatus`, `Recipients` (a collection of recipients, would need to be converted to a string), and more. You can see a full list of all attributes of any expression in debug mode by checking out view>Locals Window.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your hint. I tried it out and it works well. Now I can able to export mail body also to Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
Sub Import_Outlook_to_Excel()
    Dim oitem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim i As Long
    Sub all_folder_scan()
    'Tools Reference Microsoft Outlook
    Dim olapp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olappns As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim oinbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim oFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    i = 2 
    'tools->refrence->microsoft outlook
    Set olapp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olappns = olapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    ' set inbox folder
    Set oinbox = olappns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
        'For Each oitem In oinbox.Items.Restrict("[UnRead] = True")
            Sheets("All Folders Scan").Cells(i, 5).Value = oitem.Subject
            Sheets("All Folders Scan").Cells(i, 4).Value = oitem.SenderEmailAddress
            Sheets("All Folders Scan").Cells(i, 3).Value = oitem.SenderName
            Sheets("All Folders Scan").Cells(i, 6).Value = oitem.Body
            Sheets("All Folders Scan").Cells(i, 7).Value = oitem.ReceivedTime
            Sheets("All Folders Scan").Cells(i, 2).Value = oinbox.Name
            Sheets("All Folders Scan").Cells(i, 1).Value = oinbox.FolderPath
            i = i + 1
        'Next
        For Each oFolder In oinbox.Folders
            Call subfolders_go(oFolder)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub subfolders_go(oParent As Outlook.Folder)
    Dim oFolder1 As Outlook.MAPIFolder
        For Each oitem In oParent.Items.Restrict("[UnRead] = True")
            Sheets("All Folders Scan").Cells(i, 5).Value = oitem.Subject
            Sheets("All Folders Scan").Cells(i, 4).Value = oitem.SenderEmailAddress
            Sheets("All Folders Scan").Cells(i, 3).Value = oitem.SenderName
            Sheets("All Folders Scan").Cells(i, 6).Value = oitem.Body  
            Sheets("All Folders Scan").Cells(i, 7).Value = oitem.ReceivedTime
            Sheets("All Folders Scan").Cells(i, 2).Value = oParent.Name 
            Sheets("All Folders Scan").Cells(i, 1).Value = oParent.FolderPath 
            i = i + 1   
        Next  
        If (oParent.Folders.Count > 0) Then
            For Each oFolder1 In oParent.Folders
                Call subfolders_go(oFolder1)
            Next
        End If 
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. Will this code satisfy my needs? because I could see "From " condition and Excel sheet path are missing. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an option for objMail.comments or objMail.body. You can then export that to another column?